# Parameterized Query OR Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, itemscontrol, itemsource

I want to be able to use a QueryString parameter with a control parameter in an OR Clause on the ASPX page.

The below works for QueryString Parameter

```
Select * From Data1

WHERE        ([Customer Name] = @C) 
AND ([Order Number] = @O) 
AND ('AD\' + Salesperson_AD_User_ID = @U)
AND ([Warehouse Id] = @W)
AND ([Use Description] is NOT NULL)


        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:querystringparameter QueryStringField="C" Name="C" />
            <asp:querystringparameter QueryStringField="O" Name="O" />
            <asp:querystringparameter QueryStringField="U" Name="U" />
            <asp:querystringparameter QueryStringField="W" Name="W" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

Below does not work

```
select * From Data1

WHERE ([Customer Name] = @Customer_Name OR [Customer Name] = @C) 
AND ([Order Number] = @Order_Number OR [Order Number] = @O) 
AND ('AD\' + Salesperson_AD_User_ID = @username OR'AD\' + Salesperson_AD_User_ID = @U) 
AND ([Warehouse Id] = @Warehouse_Id OR [Warehouse Id] = @W) 
AND ([Use Description] IS NOT NULL)
```

The full name is the control parameter (textbox, dropdown, etc.)
(@Customer_Name, @Order_Number, @username, @Warehouse_Id)

and the letter is the Querystring
(@C,@O,@W, @U)

```
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:controlparameter ControlID="DropDownListCustomer" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Customer_Name" />
            <asp:querystringparameter QueryStringField="C" Name="C" />
            <asp:controlparameter ControlID="DropDownListContract" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Order_Number" />
            <asp:querystringparameter QueryStringField="O" Name="O" />
            <asp:controlparameter ControlID="UserID" PropertyName="Text" Name="username" />
            <asp:querystringparameter QueryStringField="U" Name="U" />
            <asp:controlparameter ControlID="DropDownListLocation" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Warehouse_Id" />
            <asp:querystringparameter QueryStringField="W" Name="W" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

How can I add An OR Clause to default to the control if the QueryString is not provided or if the QueryString contains a value use it?

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work. Do you have an error message?

Comment: I just get a blank page.. So in your opinion this should work?